# Request.Form has no value when previous page is a secure page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, https, request.form

I've a search box which is on a master page. i used request.form to get the value to be searched. it is working fine when the previous page is not a secure page but such as login page and other web page that is secure i get nothing value. any idea on how i can work-around this?

I forgot to mention that I'm using postbackurl to go to the target page.

```
<div class="search-div">
   <asp:TextBox ID="searchBox" runat="server" Text="Type Part Number Here" style="font-weight: lighter; font-style: normal; color: #C0C0C0" onfocus="OnSearchBoxFocus('searchBox');" onblur="OnSearchBoxLostFocus('searchBox');"></asp:TextBox>

  <asp:ImageButton ID="searchButton" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" CssClass="search-button" ImageUrl="~/images/search.png" BorderWidth="0px" Width="32" Height="28" type="submit" PostBackUrl="~/SearchResults.aspx" />
</div>


If Not IsPostBack Then
  Dim strBoxName As String = PublicVariables.webSearchBoxControlName
  Dim strSearchValue As String = Request.Form(strBoxName)
End If
```

Comment: Providing the relevant code would help.

Comment: I've added some codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you use some kind of `https` to `http` automatic redirect that is not, and can not handle the post data.

The solution is to direct make the post from https to http page, eg change this:

```
 PostBackUrl="~/SearchResults.aspx"
```

to

```
 PostBackUrl="http://example.com/dir/SearchResults.aspx"
```

I test that and is working, from one https page post to a new diferent http page.

Comment: thanks for your idea. i tried it but still unable to get the value from the searchBox using Request.Form. Should i use other method of fetching data from secure page?

Comment: could it be that the correct question is, is it possible to post data from secure page to unsecure page?

Comment: @user3590797 yes you can post data from secure to unsecure. Before answer, I make a test and the data have been readed and posted. Use this `Request.Form.ToString();` to read all the posted data to see if you have other issues.

Comment: its working, i must have put some revisions that i didn't remove when i tried your suggestion. i fix it now.

Comment: is there a way to suppress the pop-up confirmation that appears before redirecting the user to the target page?

Comment: @user3590797 This is come from the browser - Its not possible to suppress any pop-up confirmation like that. The reason is that from a non secure page, you send the data un-secure. The secure page is not help any more and there is no reason to exist in the first page. What is usually done, is to send from http to https, so the post data be safe and the new https page starts with safe encrypted transfer data, not the opposite as you do.